# How to search Floor for Player and Ghost and create instance to pass to characters

Tags: c++, vector, maze

Okay, so I'm having a lot of trouble grasping vectors and passing instances to vectors. So what I'm trying to do here is find the character 'P' in my maze, then create a player instance and push the instance into my characters vector. Then same for ghosts, but I'm sure the statements are similar.

Here is what I have, but it obviously does not compile as it is incorrect.

```
void Game::populateMaze()
{
vector<char>::iterator p, g;
while (!m_floor[0].eof()) //read in FloorA
{
    for (int rows = 0; rows < sizeof (*m_floor); rows++)
    { for (int columns = 0; columns < sizeof (*m_floor); columns++)
        {
        characters.push_back(m_floor); //push to Floor constructor
        }
    }
}
p = find (characters.begin(), characters.end(), 'P'); //search for 'P'
    while (p != vector.end())
        p = characters.push_back(Player[p]); //save location in characters as Player
g = find (characters.begin(), characters.end(), 'G'); //search for 'G'
    while (g != vector.end())
        g = characters.push_back(Ghost[g]); //save location in characters as Ghost
}
}
```

**EDIT**

Above my populateMaze() function, here is m_floor:

```
void Floor::Read (const char * filename)
{
size_t row = 0;
ifstream input(filename);

while (row < ROWS && input >> tiles[row++]);

}
void Game::readFloors()
{
m_floor[0].Read("FloorA.txt");
m_floor[1].Read("FloorB.txt");
m_floor[2].Read("FloorC.txt");

}
```

and header

```
class Floor {

const static int ROWS = 20;
const static int COLS = 30;
char tiles[ROWS][COLS];
public:
Floor();
void Read (const char * filename);
void placePlayer();
void Print() const;
bool legal_move(int x, int y) const;
istream eof();
};

class Game {
private:
Floor m_floor [3];
vector<char> characters;
public:
void readFloors();
void populateMaze();
void leave_floor();
};
```

I think my while loop is also incorrect but it's not giving me any errors. In my header I declared `istream eof();` and in Game I have `Floor m_floor[3]` because there are three separate floors to work with. Also `vector<char> characters` is in Game.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please append your post to show declaration of `m_floor`.

Comment: Okay, I added the functions that are above populateMaze().

Comment: Let me clarify.  Please add the code where you define the type of `m_floor`, not the methods.  Is the variable a vector?  A vector of *what*?

Comment: Oh okay, sorry. Perhaps I'm using it incorrectly, but I want to read in the floor and basically push the elements to a vector so players and ghosts can be pushed to the vector.